# Mapstruct How to generate mapping source/target in txt file at build time

Tags: annotations, mapstruct

I need to generate somewhere (maybe in directory "target/generated/annotations/..../ MyMapper.txt at buildtime) all the sources/target by mapper.

to then be able to read the txt files at runtime

example :

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {
        @Mapping(target = "a", source = "source.x.y.z")
        @Mapping(target = "b", source = "source.r.s.t")
        @Mapping(target = "c", source = "source.o.p.q")
    MyObject map(MySource source);
}
```

Content of the generated file : target/generated/annotations/MyMapper.txt

```
mypackage.MyObject.a=mypackage.MySource.x.y.z
mypackage.MyObject.b=mypackage.MySource.r.s.t
mypackage.MyObject.c=mypackage.MySource.o.p.q
```

how can i do that?

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

MapStruct cannot do this out of the box.

You'll need to write your own annotation processor that will use the `@Mapper` annotation and generate your own text file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Filip for your advice,

I post here a solution, which maybe can help others.

@Filip : What do you think about this solution?

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes({ "org.mapstruct.Mapping", "org.mapstruct.Mappings" })
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
@AutoService(Processor.class)
public class MapperProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    private static final String SOURCE = "source";
    private static final String TARGET = "target";
    private static final Pattern PATTERN_TARGET = Pattern.compile(".*" + TARGET + "=\"([^\"]*)\".*");
    private static final Pattern PATTERN_SOURCE = Pattern.compile(".*" + SOURCE + "=\"([^\"]*)\".*");
    private static final String DEST_PATH = "META-INF/mapstruct/";

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {

        processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, " MapperProcessor : creating metadata from mapstruct annotation");

        // init param
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> globalMapping = new HashMap<>();

        /////////// annotation : @Mappings
        for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Mappings.class)) {
            final String className = ((TypeElement) element.getEnclosingElement()).getQualifiedName().toString();
            Map<? extends ExecutableElement, ? extends AnnotationValue> elementValues = element.getAnnotationMirrors().get(0).getElementValues();
            elementValues.values().forEach(value -> {
                Map<String, String> mapTargetSource = getTargetSourceValue((List<?>) value.getValue());
                globalMapping.put(className, mapTargetSource);
            });
        }

        /////////// annotation : @Mapping
        for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Mapping.class)) {
            final String className = ((TypeElement) element.getEnclosingElement()).getQualifiedName().toString();

            List<? extends AnnotationMirror> annotationMirrors = element.getAnnotationMirrors();

            Map<? extends ExecutableElement, ? extends AnnotationValue> elementValues = annotationMirrors.get(0).getElementValues();

            String target = null;
            String source = null;

            for (Entry<? extends ExecutableElement, ? extends AnnotationValue> entrySet : elementValues.entrySet()) {
                final ExecutableElement key = entrySet.getKey();
                final AnnotationValue value = entrySet.getValue();

                if (StringUtils.equals(key.getSimpleName(), TARGET)) {
                    target = value.getValue().toString();
                }

                if (StringUtils.equals(key.getSimpleName(), SOURCE)) {
                    source = value.getValue().toString();
                }

                if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(target, source)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            Map<String, String> mapTargetSource = new HashMap<>();
            mapTargetSource.put(target, source);
            globalMapping.put(className, mapTargetSource);
        }

        writeMetaData(globalMapping);

        return true;
    }

    ///////////////// private methods

    private Map<String, String> getTargetSourceValue(List<?> listValue) {
        final Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        listValue.forEach(objValueBrut -> {
            String target = getValue(PATTERN_TARGET, objValueBrut.toString());
            String source = getValue(PATTERN_SOURCE, objValueBrut.toString());
            if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(target, source)) {
                result.put(target, source);
            }
        });
        return result;
    }

    private static String getValue(Pattern pattern, String valueBrut) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(valueBrut);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            return matcher.group(1);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void writeMetaData(Map<String, Map<String, String>> globalMapping) {
        for (Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entrySet : globalMapping.entrySet()) {

            String className = entrySet.getKey();
            Map<String, String> mapping = entrySet.getValue();

            if (mapping.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }

            try {
                FileObject resource = processingEnv.getFiler().createResource(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, "", DEST_PATH + className + ".txt");
                try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(resource.openWriter())) {
                    mapping.forEach((k, v) -> out.println(k + "=" + v));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```